# K-shortest paths using networkx package in python

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, osmnx

I have created a multidigraph of motorway of Netherlands using osmnx package. [image: Motorway network of the Netherlands]

The graph is a multidigraph returned from osmnx. Since I am interested to compute k-shortest paths between an origin and a destination, I tried networkx library. However, networkx does not seem to work with multidigraph. All I can compute the shortest path.

I would like to ask if there is any other way to perform the k-shortest path computation in python over multidigraph.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the networkx command `shortest_simple_paths` ([documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/simple_paths.html)).

It returns a generator which returns one path at a time from shortest to longest.

```
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
X = nx.shortest_simple_paths(G, 0, 5)
k = 5
for counter, path in enumerate(X):
     print(path)
     if counter == k-1:
         break
> [0, 5]
> [0, 6, 5]
> [0, 10, 5]
> [0, 6, 16, 5]
> [0, 4, 6, 5]
```

This will work with `DiGraph`s, but I'm not sure about a `MultiDiGraph`.  It's not clear to me that a road network would be a MultiDiGraph, however.

Comment: The output of nx.info(graph) reveals that the graph is multidigraph. 
However when I tried running nx.shortest_simple_paths(graph, origin,destination), it outputs: networkx.exception.NetworkX NotImplemented: not implemented for multigraph type

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be a multidigraph rather than just a DiGraph?  If you were to create a DiGraph out of it, would you be losing any information?

Comment: Real-world street networks are often MultiDiGraphs. However, it's worth checking your specific case to see if this matters or not. For example, if your graph contains no parallel edges, then you can convert it to a networkx DiGraph with no loss of information. Moreover, if it contains very few parallel edges, you can convert it to a networkx DiGraph with minimal (and presumably acceptable) loss of information. This opens up your model to networkx algorithms that only can be run on DiGraph objects.

Comment: If I convert it to Digraph, I am not able to plot the route. osmnx plot function only works with the mulitdigraph.

Comment: You could create a copy which is a DiGraph version and run the networkx algorithm.  I don't see any parallel edges in your case, so this is likely to not lose anything.  You could then use the paths from the DiGraph and your original MultiDiGraph.  Otherwise, perhaps you can modify the networkx code, but I'm not sure how difficult that would be.

Answer (score 1):

Now, osmnx has `k_shortest_paths` method implemented for multidigraph, you can use it as follows.

```
ox.routing.k_shortest_paths(G, s, t, k)
```